# Reinvolk a thread for Android after its closed in an orderly fashion

Tags: android, multithreading

I have a declaration like this:

```
// Background doer  
Thread BgThread = new Thread() {

  @Override 
  public void run() {
    aBgCounter = 0 ;
    boolean stopNow = false ;

    try {
      while( !stopNow ) {
        sleep( 1000 ) ;
        WriteOnThatLogCat( "BgThread " + String.valueOf( aBgCounter ) ) ;
        aBgCounter++ ;
          if( aBgCounter > 12 ) stopNow = true ;
      }
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
      e.printStackTrace() ;
    }
  }
};
```

Its invoked like this successfully, when its done ( just counts to 12 into a logcat ). the process dies correctly. Its started like this:

```
WriteOnThatLogCat("Issue BgThread.start() from 6") ;
BgThread.start() ;
```

This is of course just the flow control for something more involved. Anyway, later the program decides to do the same thing again, and wants to call the thread again. I read the thread can't be reused, but I really want to be able to reuse the identifier, etc so many threads can be invoked which do specific things, live and die themselves and be reused. I tried = NULL and all sorts of stuff. How can I modify the above so some fragment like:

```
WriteOnThatLogCat("Issue BgThread.start() from 6") ;
BgThread.start() ;
```

Can get a new thread and do its thing anytime ? I think its disorderly to make each kind of thread as a goal process have to sleep and try to restart itself, it seems like the correct way is have it do its thing and kill itself then just be remade when needed. I'm surprised I'm so lost on this.

thanks Dan

Answer (score 0):

An alternative is to use Android's structure for "looping" threads. See
[Processes and Threads](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/processes-and-threads.html) for an intro. The javadoc for the [Handler](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html) class shows you how to run a thread that loops, getting information from a queue of messages.

Another option, and one you really should consider, is to use an [IntentService](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/IntentService.html).